# How to use light secondary color in material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I have this theme

```
 palette: {
primary: {
  main: '#d05ce3',
},
secondary: {
  light: '#0066ff',
  main: '#0044ff',

},
```

I can use secondary color like this find

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
              <Checkbox
                color="secondary"
```

But how to use the light secondary ? in `ThemeProvider`

Like `color="secondary.light"` does not work!

Comment: Checkbox only supports strings of "primary", "secondary", or "default" for the [color prop](https://material-ui.com/api/checkbox/#props). The "light" variation is used automatically for some component aspects (e.g. [here in LinearProgress](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/54ce0fa3124887e8d3bdd312a8feff9a6caf58cd/packages/material-ui/src/LinearProgress/LinearProgress.js#L23)), but it isn't available as a choice in a color prop like this.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Thank you, but If I want to use the light secondary the one I add or the one that is auto generated how to use it? `color="secondary.light"` ?

Comment: What I'm saying is that it isn't possible via the color prop. The only way to achieve this would be to customize the [CSS for the Checkbox](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Checkbox/Checkbox.js#L40) using `withStyles`. Alternatively, you could create another theme where you use the lighter color as secondary.main and leverage that new theme for displaying the Checkbox.

Comment: @RyanCogswell I did understand about the checkbox, I meant besides the checkbox, How can I access to `secondary.light` ? I cannot access it anywhere using the color prop?

Answer (score 2):

You would have to declare a class to your checkbox, and in your css you indicate that you use the color you want. Example:

```
<ThemeProvider theme = {theme}>
          <Checkbox
            color = "secondary"
            className = {classes.checkboxColor}
             />
```

CSS file:

```
checkboxColor: {
    color: theme.palette.secondary.light
  }
```

Comment: How do I import the theme.js to my .sass to use `theme.palette.secondary.light` ? Is there any way I can access my `createMuiTheme` colors from my sass files?

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/';
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
      number: {
        color: theme.palette.secondary.main
      }
    }));
```

In return

```
const classes = useStyles();
return(
    <div>
      <Typography variant="h3" className={classes.number}>
        5
      </Typography>
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Box component.

```
<Box color='text.secondary'>
...
</Box>
```

Comment: I haven't got this working on a typography component

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using the `sx` property which can be applied on the `mui components`
For example

```
    <Checkbox
        color = "secondary"
        sx={{backgroundColor:"secondary.light"}}
    />
```